# How to display all table names once followed by all column names in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

My requirement is to display the table name once followed by all column names of that table. I am not able to do that. And I wanted it to be done with query itself not with the stored procedure. Always, it repeats the table names with the column names. 
I want table name(Entity) to be displayed once and all the column names(attributes) to be displayed under that. Then next table name(Entity) followed by its column names(attributes) and so on.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you join tables to columns every row will have a table name and a column name. When the first column of a table appears you want to display the table name and on the next line the column name. When the second (and all other) columns of that table appear you only want to display the column name. To know whether you are looking at the first column name of the table you have to number the rows in the table group. When the row number is 1 you're dealing with the first column in the group.

Try this:

```
SELECT case when row_number() over (partition by t.name order by  t.name)=1 then
     t.name + char(13)  + char(9) + c.name
else
    char(9) + c.name
end as Columns

FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c 
    ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID

ORDER BY t.name
, c.name
```

Albert